# .add() In Swing using multiple arguments

Tags: java, swing, textarea, jtextarea

Is it possible to add many, saw `JTextArea` instances with one `.add()` statement when working with a GUI?

I have over 60 in my entire getup, and want to add em all without 60+statements. I tried google but didn't find anything. I cannot really grasp some of the official docs, they seem a touch over my head.

Comment: *"and want to add em all without 60+statements."*  Use a loop.  Or better still, swap the 60 x `JTextField` for 1 x `JList`.

Comment: What are those JTextArea-s? Are they instantiated already? How do you keep them (in collection, array?) or you just want to create them automatically?

Comment: BTW *"I cannot really grasp some of the official docs, they seem a touch over my head."*  If asking for help understanding them is also beyond your ability, I suggest you look to a different field for a career.  To get a good productivity with coding it is vital to be able to read them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting them into a `List<JTextArea> areaList` and then add them using a foreach cycle.

```
private void addTextAreas(List<JTextArea> areaList)
{
    for(JTextArea textArea : areaList)
    {
        // "something" is the element you want to add them to
        something.add(textArea); 
    }
}
```